# Filling Stash from Another Controller's Action

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have an action in one controller that needs some db records stashed to render a table.

I have an action in a second controller that fills a very similar table, and so the data in its own stash is the same as I need for the first one.

Without duplicating a bunch of code in both controllers, is there a way to use one action to fill the stash of the other?

**EDIT:**
In response to code request (somewhat simplified, but should get the gist across):

In Contoller::ShoppingCart

```
sub data : Chained('base') PathPart('') CaptureArgs(0) {
my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

my $query = DBRESULTS;
    my $count = 20;

$c->stash(
    data         => $items,
    dataRowCount => scalar @$items,
    totalCount   => $count,
    pageSize     => $pageSize,
);
}
```

In Controller::Vendor

```
sub viewform : Chained('row') Args(1) {
    my ( $self, $c, $view ) = @_;

    $c->stash(
        template => 'simpleItem.mas',
        view => $view,
    );
}
```

The simpleItem.mas template requires data, dataRowCount, totalCount, pageSize, so grabbing the stash from Controller::ShoppingCart::pageData would be ideal.

Comment: Could we see your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply `$c->forward()` to the specific action you need.

```
sub viewform : Chained('row') Args(1) {
    my ( $self, $c, $view ) = @_;

    $c->forward('Controller::ShoppingCart', 'data', [ @optional_args ]);

    $c->stash(
        template => 'simpleItem.mas',
        view => $view,
    );
}
```

[All the gory details](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst#REQUEST-FLOW-HANDLING), including the siblings of `forward()`, like `detach()`, `go()` and `visit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain both actions off of another function, say in `Root.pm`, that would get these db records and put them in the stash for you.

i.e.:

```
# in Root.pm
sub get_db_stuff :Path('') :Args(0) {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    #store stuff in stash
    $c->stash->{db} = #get db records
}
```

Then your in your other controllers where your actions are you would need these two functions:

```
sub base : Chained('/get_db_stuff') PathPrefix CaptureArgs(0) {}

sub use_db_stuff : Chained('base') PathPart Args(0) {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_; 

    #db records now accessible through $c->stash->{db}
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately, they are both already pretty dependent on chains themselves, so I can't really change what they are chained to.